# HTML+PHP form not sending to my email

Tags: php, html, forms

Lots of similar questions have been asked, but couldn't find an answer to the exact problem I have. I have a form that works completely fine, but I asked someone to design it nicer (which he did) and now it just doesn't work anymore. I don't know what's causing it.

I'm assuming there is something wrong in my HTML code for the form, since the .php page works perfectly fine (I copy/pasted it entirely) on my previous page.

Any idea?

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<div class="row has-form">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Prénom *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nom *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Téléphone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comments" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Votre critique *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

your inputs have no "name" attribute add a "name" attribute with the same value as the "id" attribute to each input tag as 
Php uses NAME as the identifier when posted.

To Clearify:

if you try and get an input value from the POST in PHP you have to use the following code:

```
$var = $_POST['IDENTIFIER'];
```

Where `IDENTIFIER` is the value of the "name" attribute of the `INPUT` or `TEXTAREA` or any other `HTML FORM` element you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: explain why same value as the 'id' ?

Comment: Since it seems like he has the identifier for the input tags in his ID attribute. but PHP post uses name attribute as identifier.

Comment: It is not mandatory but does make it easier to maintain. Only radios would need separate IDs

Comment: Still, if you don't have a name tag to identify your inputs (so you can do : $_POST['identifier'] and get its value) you wont be getting any results from your form.

Comment: he doesn't post any php code in his question, he may or may not use id as identifier in php post, right ? so everyone will be easily misguided when you say "  '"name" attribute with the same value as the "id" attribute'

Comment: I don't think you can even use id as identifier when getting post values in PHP. I'll add a bit of clearification.

Answer (score 0):

all your inputs need attribute `name="first_name"` and etc:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name">
```

html_form_send.php must looks like:

```
<?php 
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
     $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
     $comments = $_POST['comments'];

     //preparing mail data
     $from = $email;
     $to = "yourmail@exemple.com";
     $subject = "Sending Form From site";
     $message = "First name: $first_name \r\nLast name:$last_name \r\nTelephone: $telephone \r\nComments: $comments";
     $headers = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
     //sending 
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   }
?>
```